# How to use ISpStreamFormatConverter?

Tags: winapi, audio, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, sapi

I am trying to convert raw PCM stream collected from a microphone (48,000 Hz) to a wave format (44,100 Hz) that `ISpRecognizer` will recognize (it returns `AUDCLNT_E_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT` from `SetRecoState(SPRST_ACTIVE_ALWAYS)` for a 48,000 Hz PCM stream but works fine for a 44,100 Hz WAV file).

I create an instance of the `ISpStreamFormatConverter` interface, supply it with my existing stream using `ISpStreamFormatConverter::SetBaseStream()` passing my own implementation of `ISpStreamFormat` that sits on top of an existing `IStream`. `ISpStreamFormatConverter` successfully calls my implementation of `ISpStreamFormat::GetFormat`, but when I call `ISpStreamFormatConverter::RemoteRead()` or `ISpStreamFormatConverter::RemoteCopyTo(),` I always get `SPERR_UNINITIALIZED` error code.

Do I need to perform any additional steps before the conversion can proceed? I could not find any examples of using the `ISpStreamFormatConverter` interface.

UPDATE. This is the code (Delphi) that attempst to use ISpStreamFormatConverter:

```
res := CoCreateInstance(CLASS_SpStreamFormatConverter,
   nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
   IID_ISpStreamFormatConverter,
   SpStreamFormatConverter);
if CheckFunction(res, 'CoCreateInstance(CLASS_SpStreamFormatConverter)') then begin
  fFileStream.Position := 0;
  //TSpStreamFormat is my own class that implemaants ISpStreamFormat
  iSourceStream := TSpStreamFormat.Create(fFileStream, fCaptureWaveFormatEx) as ISpStreamFormat;
  res := SpStreamFormatConverter.SetBaseStream(SpeechLib_TLB.ISpStreamFormat(iSourceStream), 0, 0);
  if CheckFunction(res, 'ISpStreamFormatConverter.SetBaseStream)') then begin
    res := SpStreamFormatConverter.ResetSeekPosition;
    if CheckFunction(res, 'ISpStreamFormatConverter.ResetSeekPosition)') then begin
      res := cpRecognizer.SetInput(SpStreamFormatConverter, 1);
      if CheckFunction(res, 'ISpRecognizer.SetInput') then begin
        res := cpRecognizer.SetRecoState(SPRST_ACTIVE_ALWAYS);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Looking at some (internal) examples of ISpStreamFormatConverter, it's designed to convert between known audio formats.   Since ISpStreamFormatConverter extends ISpStreamFormat, typically you just pass the ISpStreamFormatConverter to ISpRecognizer::SetInput.   So it's not clear to me why you're calling ISpStreamFormatConverter::RemoteRead in the first place.

Comment: I pass ISpStream to ISpRecognizer::SetInput. ISpStream  is retrieved from SPBindToFile. So if I pass ISpStreamFormatConverter,  ISpRecognizer will request the format it likes instead of what I have in the WAV file?

Comment: That didn't help - I still get SPERR_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT from ISpRecognizer.SetRecoState(SPRST_ACTIVE_ALWAYS)..

Comment: I have the same problem with listen.exe from  Matthew's blog (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matthew_van_eerde/2014/07/11/using-the-speech-api-to-convert-speech-to-text/) - ERROR:ISpRecoGrammar::SetDictationState failed: hr = 0x80045003

Comment: Eric, is this the right sequence of steps when using ISpStreamFormatConverter - 1. create an instance of ISpStreamFormatConverter, 2. call ISpStreamFormatConverter::SetBaseStream passing my own implementation of ISpStreamFormat. 3. ISpStreamFormatConverter calls my implementation of ISpStreamFormat::GetFormat 4. Call ISpRecognizer.SetInput 5. Call ISpRecognizer::SetRecoState(SPRST_ACTIVE_ALWAYS).

Comment: You can alternatively convert 48 to 44.1 using [Audio Resampler DSP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819070).

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Yes, that should be the correct calling sequence.  Can you post the code that you're using to initialize the ISpStreamFormatConverter?

Comment: @Eric Brown. Please see the updated question above. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing one step - after calling

```
SpStreamFormatConverter.SetBaseStream(SpeechLib_TLB.ISpStreamFormat(iSourceStream), 0, 0);
```

you need to call [SetFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms719476(v=vs.85).aspx) to define the output format:

```
SpStreamFormatConverter.SetFormat(SPDFID_WaveFormatEx,pConvertedWaveFormatEx);
```

(I'm not familiar with Delphi, so it's likely you'll have to tweak this somewhat to compile.)

Comment: I get SPERR_UNSUPPORTED_FORMAT - the WANEFORMATEX structure is (1, 2, 44100, 176400, 4, 16, 0).

Comment: If I pass the source format (1, 2, 48000, 384000, 8, 32, 0), I get back S_OK.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Have you read the remarks on SpStreamFormatConverter?  In particular, it relies on existing audio codecs to do the conversion, and if the format isn't described by one of the existing [SPSTREAMFORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717276(v=vs.85).aspx) enumerations, it's likely that you'll get SPERR_UNSUPPORTEDFORMAT.

Comment: Isn't  (1, 2, 44100, 176400, 4, 16, 0) the standard SPSF_44kHz16BitStereo format?

Comment: The only reason I am converting to the SPSF_44kHz16BitStereo format is because ISpRecognizer can handle that format, but it cannot handle SPSF_48kHz16BitStereo

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko The problem is that your *source* stream format isn't supported.   In particular, what you've specified is a 32-bit stereo format, not a 16-bit stereo format.   SPSF_48KHz16BitStereo has a WAVEFORMATEX of {1, 2, 48000, 192000, 4, 16, 0}.

Comment: Ah! That makes perfect sense - my WAVEFORMATEX came from IAudioClient.GetMixFormat. I tried SPSF_44kHz16BitStereo, but that format was not supported by my microphone. SPSF_48kHz16BitStereo (16 bit instead of 32) seems to be supported. What is the best practice for requesting a particular format from a microphone? Get the default one and try to find the best matching standard format? Note that I still had to convert from SPSF_48kHz16BitStereo to SPSF_44kHz16BitStereo - otherwise SP would return an error. Is there a list of formats that ISpRecognizer will work with?